# Node JS Read display Console output on user's device

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, console

Is it possible to display the default console output from a node.js Server to the users client? 
**I've tried several plugins like e.g. 'console.re'** but not one of them worked for me.

I like to read the 'console.log' output in real time and display all output to a client (mobile device).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

console.log writes to `stdout`, so you can listen to it and do whatever with the data.

> **console.log([data,][args])**
>
> Prints to stdout with newline.

https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

Try advancing this code:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr'])
const collectedData = []

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString())
    collectedData.push({ event: 'CONSOLE_LOG', data })
    // now just make the client consume collectedData in real-time
    // or on refresh
})

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString())
})

ls.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString())
})
```

Child processes are built in. Take a sample through these docs here:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

I don't know anything about your setup, but if you want super easy in Express

```
app.get('/logging', (req, res) => {
    res.send(collectedData)
})
```

Make the client hit it every 2000ms or something.

Otherwise, you need to create a socket with the server and push updates to the client, and handle them in the client.

- http://www.socket.io

You can also setup TCP and UDP sockets fairly quick in node.js. Do some Googling.

I have some sample code I can give you:

```
/**
 * SERVER
 */

// Load dgram module
const dgram = require('dgram')
// Create new socket
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4')

// Listening event
server.on('listening', () => console.log('UDP Server listening'))
// Message event
server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(`${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port} - ${msg}`)
});

// Start UDP socket listener
const PORT = 3333
const HOST = '127.0.0.1'
server.bind(PORT, HOST)

/**
 * CLIENT
 */

const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
const ip = require('ip')

client.send('Sample message', PORT, HOST, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`UDP message sent: ${ip.address()}`)
  client.close()
})
```